# Dispose of pages that used stateful shell root feature in GoRouter package

Tags: flutter-state, flutter-go-router

I'm using stateful shell route (GoRouter) and I want to dispose of these pages at sometimes. What is the solution?

[StatefulShellRoute link](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart)

Tip: StatefulShellRoute keep the state of pages with global key

Dispose pages these used statefulShellRoute to keep state.